# Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I got the this result

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array
>
> Filename: controllers/Threads.php
>
> Line Number: 48
>
> Backtrace:

This is my codes in Controller

```
// category
public function threadsview($slug) {
    // get threads category
    $data['item'] = $this->threads_model->getThreadsCategory($slug);

    $data['title'] = $data['item']['catname'];
    $data['desc'] = '';

    $this->load->view('themes/default/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('threads/threadsview', $data);
    $this->load->view('themes/default/footer');
}
```

And the codes in my Model

```
 //get threads categories by slug
    public function getThreadsCategory($slug) {
        $this->db->order_by('id','asc');
        $this->db->where('slug',$slug);
        $query = $this->db->get('threads_cat');
        return $query;
    }
```

The error is from this code

```
$data['title'] = $data['item']['catname'];
```

I hope someone can help me regarding on this..

Comment: `$data['item']` is not an array. check if it's an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your response I`ve made it and its working now

```
public function threadsview($slug) {
        // get threads category
        $data['item'] = $this->threads_model->getThreadsCategory($slug);
        if($data['item']->num_rows()<=0){
            $data['title'] = 'Opps!, 404 page not found';
            $this->load->view('themes/default/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('errors/html/error_404');
            $this->load->view('themes/default/footer');
        }else
        foreach ($data['item']->result() as $res) {


        $data['title'] = $res->catname;
        $data['desc'] = $res->description;

        $this->load->view('themes/default/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('threads/threadsview', $data);
        $this->load->view('themes/default/footer');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is get a result or row, and then check if there was anything in it. So when you do your query:

```
$query = $this->db->get('threads_cat');
```

Before you return anything you should do this:

```
if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    return $query->result_array();
}

return FALSE;
```

Or if you are just expecting a single row:

```
if( $query->num_rows() == 1 )
{
    return $query->row_array();
}

return FALSE;
```

Be sure to check if `$data['item'] == FALSE` before trying to use it:

```
if( $data['item'] !== FALSE && is_array( $data['item'] ) )
{
    // $data['item'] is an array and can be used as an array
}
```

Comment: Thank you dude I`ve already figure it out and its working now

Comment: Glad to hear it. Be sure to give some credits if credits are due.

Comment: Yeah sure.. by the way I appreciate your help.

Comment: So many people get tripped up over this. I would add, generally instead of checking if it is an array, check if it has any rows! `count($result) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your returning an array or an object in your modal

`$data['item'] = $this->threads_model->getThreadsCategory($slug);`

in your model if your using

`$this->db->from($table);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();` // this is returning the first row as object & not array

In controller

`$data['title'] = $data['item']->catname;`

for array you could use something like this

`$query->first_row('array');` //this is returning the first row as Array

In controller

`$data['title'] = $data['item']['catname'];`

//if your still having a problem you could print your data
in controller just comment your load->view()
and add this line

`print_r("<pre>");
print_r($data['item']);
print_r("</pre>");`

Answer (score 0):

`$data['item']` is not an array, probably because you didn't actually fetch the results into an array.

Inside your function, fetch first the result of the query into an array.

```
public function getThreadsCategory($slug) {
    $this->db->order_by('id','asc');
    $this->db->where('slug',$slug);
    $query = $this->db->get('threads_cat');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude but this code still not working the error is the same. And I`ve already figure out how to fixed this by the way thank you very much for your response I appreciate it.